# Sending an email containing a password reset link

Tags: php, laravel

I am building an application using laravel to manage campaign bookings. I am using the laravel auth functionality to manage logging in using an email & password (login.blade.php). When a user clicks on the 'forgot password' link below the login form and enters their email address, I would like them to be sent a password reset link. However, when the 'Send Password Reset Link' button is pressed, I get the following error: **'Connection could not be established with host mfex10 [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.]**

Anyone have any ideas as to how to solve this?

My .env file is as follows:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mfex10
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

I have tried running php artisan config:cache and php artisan cache:clear from the web server. I am using a windows system (so cannot use Sudo commands).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Rob

London, UK

[image]

Comment: Your mail server host `mfex10` does not seem to be a valid host. Double check your mail credentials.

Comment: You need to enter correct mail SMTP configuration. your host is wrong that's why it is not reachable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a full hostname for your smtp server, there is no host that is called `mfex10` so your server cannot resolve it's IP address and therefore cannot connect to it.

Usually hostnames are in a fully qualified domain name format like `smtp.mfex10.com`

If you're testing though, I recommend using a service like mailtrap.

Comment: Cheers Joe. We fixed the problem anyway by using an IP address instead of a hostname.